# How to disable call function on click

Tags: jquery

```
$('form').ketchup();
```

Form contains input with `type="submit"` and id, say, "bindOff". Is it possible not to call function  when clicking on this input?

Comment: Please elaborate, your question is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely sure of your question, but I think this is what you're asking for. It doesn't fire the click even when touching the submit button.

```
$('input#bindOff').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Is it possible to prevent calling only ketchup() function?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("form#bindOff").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault() // stops default behaviour
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the input submit:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="return false;" id="bindOff" />
```